# How to copy specific cells, and then paste them to assigned cells

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to determine whether the data in cell B6 exists on another sheet. If so, copy cells in the corresponding rows to a specific tab.

If the word "America" exists in Sheet2, the corresponding data in front of the word America (the state, zip etc.) should be pasted into specific cells in Sheet1.

I watched several YouTube videos and googled to no avail.

```vb
Sub Testbutton()
    
    a = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To a
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = .Cells(5, 5) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        End If
```

This is giving me an error for

```vb
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = .Cells(5, 5) Then
```

Comment: That line is problably giving you an error because of `.Cells(5, 5)`. That point does not refer to any [With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement). You should either add a proper With statement or cut off that point. Mind that by cutting it out, the code will refer to the cell on the 5th row and 5th column of the active sheet.

Comment: I agree, I input the domain for sheet 1 and it worked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I put together. It's a little longer than yours, but it's functionally the same idea.

Evil Blue Monkey is probably right - that `.Cells(5, 5)` is probably the issue.

I recommend avoiding `Select` as much as possible - it *really* slows down execution. There's almost always a different solution that will be faster and easier to read!

```
Sub testButton()
    
    'Declare all variables!
    Dim targetValue As Variant, thisValue As Variant, copyRows As Long, copyCols As Long, i As Long, pasteRows as Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Get Sheet Rows
        copyRows = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Get target value to test against
        targetValue = .Cells(5, 5).Value
        For i = 2 To copyRows

            'Test this cell's value against target value
            thisValue = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            If thisValue = targetValue Then

                'Copy from Sheet1
                copyCols = .Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column       'Limits the copied area only to necessary range
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, copyCols)).Copy

                'Paste to sheet2
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
                    pasteRows = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row        'Offset adds 1 row
                    .Range(.Cells(pasteRows, 1), .Cells(pasteRows, copyCols)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    'Clear clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Guys I played around with it yesterday and choose copy paste.special and it worked. Then I came back here to see similar and improved code to do exactly that. Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid select, you can use also Sheet1.Range("A1").value = Sheet1.Range("A1").value